# Xcode Project runner in TeamCity

Tags: xcode, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

What does the `install` ,`installsrc` and `test`do while using the Xcode Project runner.[image]

When I build using `clean build archive` I am getting only the `.app` and not `.ipa` .Are there any command line parameters that is to be added to the step.Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The `archive` build action generates a `.xcarchive` file. To create an `.ipa` file you have to add a subsequent command line build step in teamcity with the following command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath projectname.xcarchive -exportPath projectname -exportFormat ipa
```